# Run ASGI Application with FastAPI inside a Jelastic PaaS Environment using mod_wsgi

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, wsgi, jelastic, asgi

I want to use `FastAPI` inside my python project, I want to deploy it on a Jelastic PaaS.
Apparently `mod_wsgi` manages only WSGI application so I was trying to run an ASGI application inside a WSGI application using `a2wsgi` like this, this is my `wsgi.py`:

```
import os, sys

virtenv = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/virtenv/'
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    if sys.version.split(' ')[0].split('.')[0] == '3':
        exec(compile(open(virtualenv, "rb").read(), virtualenv, 'exec'), dict(__file__=virtualenv))
    else:
        execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass

sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser('~'))
sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser('~') + '/ROOT/')


from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


from a2wsgi import ASGIMiddleware
application = ASGIMiddleware(app)
```

And these lines have been executed for my specific `virtenv`:

```
virtualenv virtenv
source virtenv/bin/activate
pip install a2wsgi
pip install fastapi
deactivate
```

But it still does not work properly. Probably I'm missing something big.
The error doesn't seem "to talk" to me (but I'm not a python-guy):

```
mod_wsgi (pid=14438): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/webroot/ROOT/wsgi.py'.
mod_wsgi (pid=14438): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/webroot/ROOT/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/webroot/ROOT/wsgi.py", line 24, in <module>
from fastapi import FastAPI
File "/var/www/webroot/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastapi/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from .applications import FastAPI as FastAPI
File "/var/www/webroot/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 16, in <module>
from fastapi import routing
File "/var/www/webroot/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 22, in <module>
from fastapi import params
File "/var/www/webroot/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastapi/params.py", line 5, in <module>
from fastapi.openapi.models import Example
File "/var/www/webroot/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastapi/openapi/models.py", line 4, in <module>
from fastapi._compat import (
File "/var/www/webroot/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastapi/_compat.py", line 20, in <module>
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestErrorModel
File "/var/www/webroot/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastapi/exceptions.py", line 3, in <module>
from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model
File "/var/www/webroot/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
from . import dataclasses
File "/var/www/webroot/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/dataclasses.py", line 11, in <module>
from ._internal import _config, _decorators, _typing_extra
File "/var/www/webroot/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_decorators.py", line 15, in <module>
from ..fields import ComputedFieldInfo
File "/var/www/webroot/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/fields.py", line 19, in <module>
import annotated_types
File "/var/www/webroot/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/annotated_types/__init__.py", line 361, in <module>
IsNotFinite = Annotated[_NumericType, Predicate(Not(math.isfinite))]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Not() takes no arguments
```

The full context:

```
APACHE_VERSION=2.4.57
DOCKER_EXPOSED_PORT=21,22,25,443,7979,80
MOD_WSGI_VERSION=4.9.4
OWASP_MODSECURITY_CRS_VERSION=3.3.2
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PYTHON_VERSION=3.12.0
STACK_VERSION=2.4.57
VERSION=3.12.0
WEBROOT=/var/www/webroot
WSGI_SCRIPT=/var/www/webroot/ROOT/wsgi.py
```

Comment: Does this code execute successfully when you run it locally? The error suggests a coding error at `Not(math.isfinite)`

Comment: In this moment, i cannot reproduce the exact same environment locally. What I can say is that running locally the command `gunicorn wsgi:application` it runs correctly.

Comment: I managed to run the same under a docker container in jelastic, but if I manage to run it under a jelastic-python environment it would be way more better to easily configure the CI/CD.

Comment: @Damien-Layershift I finally found it, the python version was giving problem with that library. I'm going to post the full solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a simple solution.
I downgraded the jelastic `apachepython` container:

- from `2.4.57-python-3.12.0`
- to `2.4.57-python-3.9.18` or `2.4.57-python-3.11.6`

and it worked.

You can test it on your own Jelastic environment following the steps that I wrote in this public repository on github:
[danielemaddaluno/pyjel](https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/pyjel)